# Validation with Compare fails in Blazor

Tags: validation, compare, blazor

I am trying Blazor client side Form validation. Apparently the Compare validation doesn't work correctly, or I am doing something wrong.

```html
<EditForm Model="@user" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="email">Email</label>
        <InputText Class="form-control col-sm-10" id="email" bind-value="@user.Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="password">Password</label>
        <InputText Class="form-control col-10" id="password" bind-value="@user.Password" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
        <InputText Class="form-control col-10" id="confirmPassword" bind-value="@user.PasswordConfirm" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@functions {
    class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required, EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required, MinLength(6)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Compare(nameof(Password))]
        public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
    }
    private RegisterModel user = new RegisterModel();

    private void OnValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Valid");
    }
}
```

This is what happens:

1) Write a valid email

2) Write a valid password

3) Click the Register Button

Expected -> Validation Error (password fields different) and no call to OnValidSubmit

Effective -> No validation error, OnValidSubmit called.

If I write something in ConfirmPassword (different from Password), the first click detects the validation error, but the second clears the error and calls OnValidSubmit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a bug related to...

Quote:

> I found a bug the way it handles the CompareAttribute, I will try to
>   fix this and send a PR.

Source: https://remibou.github.io/Using-the-Blazor-form-validation/

See also this: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10643

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class RegisterAccountModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Compare(nameof(Password))]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

   public RegisterAccountModel registerAccountModel = new RegisterAccountModel();

   <EditForm Model="@registerAccountModel" OnValidSubmit="@RegisterUser">

        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />

        <div class="row">
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <div class="control">
                <InputText name="email" id="email" class="input" type="email" @bind-Value="@registerAccountModel.Email"></InputText>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Password</label>
            <div class="control">
                <InputText id="password" class="input" type="password" @bind-Value="@registerAccountModel.Password"></InputText>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Confirm password</label>
            <div class="control">
                <InputText id="cpassword" class="input" type="password" @bind-Value="@registerAccountModel.ConfirmPassword"></InputText>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
```

Comment: When you shared code snippet as an answer, please try to explain it too

Comment: this is pretty simple answer. No need to use various trick to compare fields by Blazor (as said enet in answer above). There are always existing future for any POCO class - we can use [Compare(nameof(Password))] attribute and this opportunity will be working perfectly and show caution for end user.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on youtube.
link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUqP-2LilAQ&t=5m24s

1. Add a nuget package: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation" checklist "Include prelease"
2. Change data annotation attribute from "Compare" to "CompareProperty".

Answer (score 0):

```
@page "/demo"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<h1>User:</h1>
<EditForm Model=@u OnSubmit=@FormSubmitted>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <InputText type="password" placeholder="Password" @bind-Value=u.Password class="form-control" id="Password" />
        <ValidationMessage For=@(() => u.Password) />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
        <InputText type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" @bind-Value=u.ConfirmPassword class="form-control" id="ConfirmPassword" />
        <ValidationMessage For=@(() => u.ConfirmPassword) />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
</EditForm>

@code
{
    user u = new user();

    void FormSubmitted()
    {
        // Post data to the server
    }

    public class user
    {
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Compare(nameof(Password), ErrorMessage = "Password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```